# WooCommerce add delivery date as hidden product in checkout (Third party payment gateway)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

Im developing an e-commerce site with wordpress and woocommerce 2.1. Im using a third party payment gateway (Klarna Checkout) which doesn't offer the customer to specify a delivery date/time. I need to make this feature available but the problem is that the gateway only sends the order-meta from their form, which doesn't offer a date field, when the order is completed. In other words, the standard checkout fields in woocommerce won't be passed to the final order.

My idea of solution is to add a hidden free product called Time, with variations for different time spans, on the checkout page and automatically add this product(with selected variation) to the cart when a customer selects a variation. The specified time would then show as a ordered product when viewing the order in wordpress. How could i do this?

If anyone has a better idea of how to solve this problem feel free to contribute :)

Thanks!

Comment: Custom checkout field doesn't work ?Lesson thre should do the trick : http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Answer (score 0):

Try this free plugin that adds a delivery date on the checkout page: http://wordpress.org/plugins/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce/